# Putting a large string into a variable with other variable within it

Tags: php, variables

Learning php and have a quick question.

I want to have a variable with the following in it

```
      $worldstyle       = $data["worldpercent"] < "75" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $USA    = $data["USApercent"] <= "22" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $bundlestyle    = $data["bundlepercent"] <= "50" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $value_datastyle  = $data["value_data2"] <= "350" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $addon            = $data["addon_products"] <= "0" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $inventoryvalue          = $data["inventoryvalue"] <= "120" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $packs        = $data["packs"] <= "1" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $trend  = round($data["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trending       = round($data["value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend2 = round($data2["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend5 = round($data5["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend6 = round($data6["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend7 = round($data7["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend8 = round($data8["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend9 = round($data9["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $worldstyleStore1      = $data["boxVal.106"] <= "75" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $USAStore1   = $data["boxVal.90"] <= "22" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $bundlestyleStore1   = $data["boxVal.74"] <= "50" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $value_datastyleStore1 = $data["value_data"] <= "$350" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $addonStore1           = $data["addon_Devices3"] <= "1" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $inventoryvalueStore1         = $data["boxVal.66"] <= "$120" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
```

So it would be something like:

```
$style_frontpage = '      $worldstyle       = $data["worldpercent"] < "75" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $USA    = $data["USApercent"] <= "22" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $bundlestyle    = $data["bundlepercent"] <= "50" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $value_datastyle  = $data["value_data2"] <= "350" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $addon            = $data["addon_products"] <= "0" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $inventoryvalue          = $data["inventoryvalue"] <= "120" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $packs        = $data["packs"] <= "1" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $trend  = round($data["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trending       = round($data["value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend2 = round($data2["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend5 = round($data5["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend6 = round($data6["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend7 = round($data7["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend8 = round($data8["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend9 = round($data9["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $worldstyleStore1      = $data["boxVal.106"] <= "75" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $USAStore1   = $data["boxVal.90"] <= "22" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $bundlestyleStore1   = $data["boxVal.74"] <= "50" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $value_datastyleStore1 = $data["value_data"] <= "$350" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $addonStore1           = $data["addon_Devices3"] <= "1" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $inventoryvalueStore1         = $data["boxVal.66"] <= "$120" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';';
```

I have tried the above but it breaks my script.

How could I have this within a variable?  I want to just type the variable instead of putting it throughout my code.

Where I am using it

```
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'front') !== false) {
        echo $worldstyle;
    } elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'page') !== false) {
        echo $worldstyle;
    } elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'product') !== false) {
        echo $worldstyle;
    } elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'sample') !== false) {
        echo $worldstyle;
    } elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'example') !== false) {
        echo $worldstyle;
    } elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'test') !== false) {
        echo $worldstyle;
    } elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'main') !== false) {
        echo $worldstyle;
    } else {
        echo $localstyle;

    }
```

I used a similar script I saw here for my styles but I think the ' and " mess it up.

I was able to get what I needed to work using a function.

```
function frontstyle(){
          $worldstyle          = $data[\"worldpercent\"] < \"75\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $USA                 = $data[\"USApercent\"] <= \"22\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $bundlestyle         = $data[\"bundlepercent\"] <= \"50\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $value_datastyle     = $data[\"value_data2\"] <= \"350\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $addon               = $data[\"addon_products\"] <= \"0\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $inventoryvalue      = $data[\"inventoryvalue\"] <= \"120\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $packs               = $data[\"packs\"] <= \"1\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $trend               = round($data[\"total_value\"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trending            = round($data[\"value\"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend2              = round($data2[\"total_value\"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend5              = round($data5[\"total_value\"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend6              = round($data6[\"total_value\"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend7              = round($data7[\"total_value\"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend8              = round($data8[\"total_value\"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend9              = round($data9[\"total_value\"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $worldstyleStore1    = $data[\"boxVal.106\"] <= \"75\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $USAStore1           = $data[\"boxVal.90\"] <= \"22\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $bundlestyleStore1   = $data[\"boxVal.74\"] <= \"50\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $value_datastyleStore1    = $data[\"value_data\"] <= \"$350\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $addonStore1              = $data[\"addon_Devices3\"] <= \"1\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';
          $inventoryvalueStore1     = $data[\"boxVal.66\"] <= \"$120\" ? ' style=\"color: red;\"' : '';

          }
```

Comment: Use heredoc https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0):

It breaks your script because you are not escaping your already present apostrophe ( `'` ).

 You could escape them using a backslash ( `\` ), or you could use [HEREDOC syntax.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) :

```
$style_frontpage = <<<SOMECOOLIDENTIFIER
 $worldstyle       = $data["worldpercent"] < "75" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $USA    = $data["USApercent"] <= "22" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $bundlestyle    = $data["bundlepercent"] <= "50" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $value_datastyle  = $data["value_data2"] <= "350" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $addon            = $data["addon_products"] <= "0" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $inventoryvalue          = $data["inventoryvalue"] <= "120" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $packs        = $data["packs"] <= "1" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $trend  = round($data["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trending       = round($data["value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend2 = round($data2["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend5 = round($data5["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend6 = round($data6["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend7 = round($data7["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend8 = round($data8["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $trend9 = round($data9["total_value"] / $dom * $daysinmonth, 2);
          $worldstyleStore1      = $data["boxVal.106"] <= "75" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $USAStore1   = $data["boxVal.90"] <= "22" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $bundlestyleStore1   = $data["boxVal.74"] <= "50" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $value_datastyleStore1 = $data["value_data"] <= "$350" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $addonStore1           = $data["addon_Devices3"] <= "1" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
          $inventoryvalueStore1         = $data["boxVal.66"] <= "$120" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
SOMECOOLIDENTIFIER;
```

Comment: I tried your sample but that also broke my page.  I added <<<STYLE and ended it with STYLE;

Comment: my bad, you need to use NOWDOC instead, change the `SOMECOOLIDENTIFIER` to `'SOMECOOLIDENTIFIER'`

Comment: In my code editor this shows as invalid as well.  When saved and tested it shows me a blank page

Comment: ok i got it.  Change just the first somecoolidentifier to 'COMECOOLIDENTIFIER' and leave the second as is

Comment: Ok so I got it to not break my code but now when I echo it, it displays all the code and does not format.

Comment: of course it does. You have you code in a string right now. Isn't that what you wanted ? @ellucidone

Comment: No .. what I wanted was to be able to reference that code elsewhere without having to copy and paste the whole thing.Sorry I should have made that clear

Comment: oh, well you need to place this code into a function and call that function from multiple places, this is a whole other things.

Comment: You could also place it into another file and call that file using `require` or `require_once`

Comment: Ok let me research that .  thank you for your help though.